# How to narrow to subtree in org agenda follow mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

When org-agenda-follow-mode is on, how do I make the buffer showing the items in the agenda narrow to the subtree of the relevant item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically all you need to do this is to have `org-narrow-to-subtree` run right after whatever function `org-follow-mode` is calling, which happen to be `org-agenda-goto`.  You have to be a little careful writing the advice because `org-agenda-goto` is sometimes called with an argument, which `org-narrow-to-subtree` can't take.  Here's what we need:

```
(advice-add 'org-agenda-goto :after
            (lambda (&rest args)
              (org-narrow-to-subtree)))
```

Comment: Excellent snippet! Is there a way to make it follow in the same window?

Comment: It's working nicely :)

Answer (score 3):

Late response, but it may be helpful to someone.

There's another possibility to view tree in indirect buffer only for item at point with `C-c C-x b`

This indirect buffer can also be used in follow mode when you set `org-agenda-follow-indirect` to non-nil value like this:

```
(setq org-agenda-follow-indirect t)
```

[Source](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/e53f62eba9569b78540481bda4b5e7a6b4016983?style=split).